# xxx.mex: failed to load: No such file or directory

Tags: octave

For some time, I've been using some .mex files I created. Now I have a new computer. I copied all the files over and reinstalled Cygwin and Octave. When I try to execute any of the .mex routines I get a message like:

```
error: testm: /cygdrive/c/A/Cwin/...../quad.mex: failed to load: No such file or directory
```

The file is definitely there and I'm having no trouble loading .m files from the same directory. It does not say there is anything wrong with the file. I'm guessing this is some sort of configuration problem. I am running Octave 4.2.1. When I start it, I get the following message:

```
Octave was configured for "x86_64-unknown-cygwin".
```

Could that have something to do with it? I think I'm developing x64 paranoia, since all my Excel .dll macros no longer work either. Thanks.

Comment: Have you compiled your .mex for 32bit systems? I guess you have to rebuild them for 64it

Comment: it's still an odd error message though ... in any case, whatever the problem, it still makes sense to rebuild the mex files; hopefully you still have the source code for them?

Comment: My old computer is on its last legs, but I was able to get it to run Octave. It is version 4.0.0 and starts with the same message about x86_64. Not sure what that means. I agree it is a strange message. The code doesn't indicate it is a mex rather than m function or where it is located. Obviously it found the file in the right place in order to produce the message that there is no file. Very strange. I'm trying to find more info about compatibility of mex files. I'm beginning to think they aren't very compatible as I had hoped.

Comment: I think I may have an idea about what's going on. The way these mex files work is that there is one main one and then one by the name of each function.. The function files are small and simply route Octave to the main file which has the code. Maybe it is somehow not able to load the main file even though it is there in the same directory. Could this be the problem?